# How do I display an Angular directive conditionally?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I'm attempting to use Angular directives to create custom input field types. For example, I have a type called "duration" which draws three separate hours, minutes, and seconds fields. I'm trying to use the directive as an attribute of an input element, and the directive replaces the input element.

For example, in the following code:

```
<input duration>
```

Would be rendered as a `<div>` with several inputs inside of it, and the original input would be out of the picture.

I'm running an `ngRepeat` loop through several form fields of different types, including `duration`. I'd like to find a way that only requires me to put one input in the HTML, with the `duration` attribute applied only if the field is supposed to be of `duration` type. I tried the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <input type='{{field}}' ng-attr-duration="field==='duration'">
</div>
```

The problem with that code is that every element is rendered as `duration` because `ng-attr-duration` gets evaluated to `duration='false'` when the field is not duration, which triggers my directive.

Is there a way for me to apply the directive conditionally without having to define multiple `<input>`s to reduce redundancy in my code?

Comment: Are you looking for ng-show? Hide/show elements based on an expression: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: Right now I'm working around it with ng-if (ng-if actually deletes the element from the DOM whereas ng-show only hides it via CSS), which helps with validation because otherwise I'd have hidden required fields and the form would never be considered valid. But either way, I'd like a way that doesn't require adding two separate input elements in the code to avoid redundancy (if possible)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at what the [directive docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings) say about `ng-attr`:

> When using ngAttr, the `allOrNothing` flag of `$interpolate` is used, so if any expression in the interpolated string results in `undefined`, the attribute is removed and not added to the element.

Note that you need to be using curly braces so Angular will interpolate the expression. And, if your expression has an undefined term in it, the attribute won't be added.

How about something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <input type='{{field}}' ng-attr-duration="{{field==='duration' ? true : undefined}}">
</div>
```

The `true` in the ternary expression can be whatever you want, just not `undefined`.

Comment: I just tried this, but unfortunately the duration attribute is still included no matter what. I also tested ng-attr-duration="undefined" and ng-attr-duration="{{undefined}}", but both of those caused the duration attribute to remain as well.

Comment: @Zak Interesting. It works when the attribute name is not a directive (I got curious and made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0BgPW9iQEdor33iPRjUd?p=preview).

Comment: @Zak oops, I forgot to save my changes in the Plunkr. It's updated now. It seems like Angular is doing the wrong thing. In my case, it's not adding the `duration` attribute, however, I still see the effects of my `duration` directive.

Answer (score 0):

What i can think of you can use condition if-else of ng-switch

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
   <div ng-switch on="field">
      <input ng-switch-when="true"  type='{{field}}' ng-attr-duration="field==='duration'">
      <input ng-switch-default="true"  type='{{field}}'>
   </div>
</div>
```

> It will also maintain readability of code.